# Drawing Multiple Rectangles c#

Tags: c#

What would be the best way to draw 25 rectangles (5*5) in c#?
I later need to be able to reach a specific rectangle and change its color, for instance change the color to red if the user inputs the incorrect word.
Would it be more suitable to create an array of rectangles in this case?

This is what i have so far

```
Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();

int x =0;
int y= 0;
int width = 20;
int height = 20;
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    if (i <= 4)
    {
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, x, y, width, height);
        x += 50;
    }
    else if (i > 4)
    {
        y = 50;
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, x, y, width, height);
        x += 50;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make non-autosized empty labels, or panels, or whatever.

Comment: A single loop is not good.  Have two loops, one nested in the other.  `for (int yPos = 0; yPos < 5; yPos++) { for (int xPos = 0; xPos < 5; xPos++) { /* code in here */ }`

Comment: Have you considered using WPF and doing this in xaml with a Canvas?

Comment: @ Kieren Johnstone I dont fully understand what your trying to do with  your code, can you be more specific. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Ran The [homework tag is officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated). Please don't use it anymore.

Comment: Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object that is bound to a control! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter..


You can test the persistance of your graphics by doing a Minimize/Maximize sequence..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started, not the complete code.  You will need to add a PictureBox control and use the default name (picurebox1).  EDIT:  Need to add a button too :)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public List<Rectangle> listRec = new List<Rectangle>();
    Graphics g;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.Size = new Size(100,20);
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        {
            rect.X = x * rect.Width;
            for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
            {
                rect.Y = y * rect.Height;
                listRec.Add(rect);
            }
        }

        foreach (Rectangle rec in listRec)
        {
            g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Blue);
            g.DrawRectangle(p, rec);
        }
    }

    public void ChangeColor(Rectangle target, Color targetColor)
    {
        Pen p = new Pen(targetColor);
        g.DrawRectangle(p, target.X, target.Y, target.Width, target.Height);
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.D0: ChangeColor(listRec[0], Color.Red);
                break;
            case Keys.D1: ChangeColor(listRec[1], Color.Red);
                break;
            //..more code to handle all keys..
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks i got it to work. If i wanted to change the color of a specific rectangle what would be the easisest way?

Comment: easiest is subjective.  You could change the color on a mouse click using the mouse position, or use a key like I do above.  Make sure that you set the form property "KeyPreview" to True or else it won't accept the key input.  All you really need is a function to change the color and then a way to determine which rectangle(s) need to change.

Comment: cool. But just one question. How to add some text inside each Rectangle, please? Thank you!

Comment: Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! The result is non-persistent!! - Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter..


You can test the persistance of your graphics by doing a Minimize/Maximize sequence..

Answer (score 0):

If you're not concerned with performance or the looks, then the easiest approach would be to create a List of Lists of Panels in your Form_Load event as one of the comments mentions.

```
List<List<Panel>> panelGrid = new List<List<Panel>>();
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{  
    var panelRow = new List<Panel>();
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        panelRow.Add(new Panel());

        // add positioning logic here
    }

    panelGrid.Add(panelRow);
}
```

Then you will be able to reference each individual one at a later stage...

If you have to use Graphics class (which is the better approach), then you should setup something similar however replacing Panel with a class of your own. Then in Form_Paint event you would iterate through the list of objects and render them.

```
class MyPanel
{
    public Size size;
    public Color color;
}

...

foreach (var myPanelRow in myPanelGrid)
    foreach (var myPanel in myPanelRow)
        g.FillRectangle(myPanel.color, myPanel.size); // this obviously won't work as is, but you get the idea
```

Then when you need to change a color, you do something like:

```
myPanelsGrid[0][0].color = Color.Blue;
myForm.Invalidate();
```

The second line will result in Paint in event being called again.

Comment: Performance is not a concern so your method using panels is fine. Could you give me an example on how to add the logic? Thanks