# Get coordinates points between x and y

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a jpeg image in a picturebox, on page load i am drawing the rectangle based on the x(150) and y(440) coordinates. now when i mousemove on the picturebox i need to identify the rectangle by their coordinates and highlight the image. for example see the below image ..

lets take the first rectangle, on mouse move any points inside the rectangle i need to perform some actions.. how to find the coordinates between these x and y for the rectangle?..

[image]

Comment: given you know thee size of the photo (assuming you've scaled them to be the same size) this is a simple mathematical problem.. one which has been solved countless times over.

Comment: bind MouseEnter and MouseLeave event of every picturbox (single event for every picturbox) and with the use of "object sender" you can add border in MouseEnter event and remove border in MouseLeave event

Comment: Are you just wanting to test if a point is inside a rectangle? In that case just define rectangle by the minimum and maximum x and y, and `if((point.x >= rectangle.min_x) && (point.x <= rectangle.max_x) && (point.y >= rectangle.min_y) && (point.y <= rectangle.max_y))` then the point is inside the rectangle

Comment: Thanks for the immediate reply guys!! yes,Basically if the mouse touches any rectangle i will open one modal window with the selected image in a bigger size with the details(name,country,state) of the pic/image populated.All the rectangle are not same in size.

Comment: Rectangle.Contains(Point)

Answer (score 1):

A rectangle has 4 Points (edges):

- Left
- Top
- Right
- Bottom

If your mouse coordinates (`MouseEventArgs` properties) are between them, the mouse pointer is in the rectangle.

Are the mouse coordinates greater than `right` or `bottom` or lower than `left` / `top`, your mouse is outside the rectangle.

Taking @samgak`s Comment:

```
if(
(point.x >= rectangle.min_x) && (point.x <= rectangle.max_x) && 
(point.y >= rectangle.min_y) && (point.y <= rectangle.max_y)) {
    //do something
}
```

and replacing `point` with `e` is exactly what you want.

Maybe the following link will help to understand:
[How to check if a point is inside a rectangle](https://martin-thoma.com/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle/)

Comment: Thanks ,samgak and Clijsters for your suggestions.it helped me to go next step.... on mouse move i created rectangle using some hard coded values and followed  the above code. it works... now i have many rectangles with images  thinking on mouse move how to dynamically create the rectangle and check the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Provided images are the same size and assuming it is stored in variable imageSize (of type System.Drawing.Size) then:

```
Size imageSize = new Size(...) // define the size here
...
int row = point.y / imageSize.height; 
int col = point.x / imageSize.width;
var rect = new Rectangle(col * imageSize.Width, row * imageSize.Height, imageSize.Width, imageSize.Height);
```

You can then use rect to draw you frame around the image (you may want to inflate the rectangle by a couple of pixels)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Samgak /Clijsters,

```
         I have completed my functionality
```

// page level declaration

```
         private Rectangle SelectedRect;
         public List<Rectangle> listRec = new List<Rectangle>();
```

// on page load add all the rectangle in the rectanglelist.

```
 private void Highlightimage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

                    {

                        for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            int x = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[i][0]);
                            int y = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[i][1]);
                            int width = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[i][2]);
                            int height = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[i][3]);
                            SelectedRect.Size = new Size(width, height);
                            SelectedRect.X = x;
                            SelectedRect.Y = y;
                            listRec.Add(SelectedRect);

                        }

                        }
```

// draw the rectangle

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)

                    { Graphics g = e.Graphics;
                            foreach (Rectangle rec in listRec)
                            {
                                Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red);
                                g.DrawRectangle(p, rec);
                            }
            }
             private Rectangle MakeRectangle(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)
                    {
                        return new Rectangle(
                            Math.Min(x0, x1),
                            Math.Min(y0, y1),
                            Math.Abs(x0 - x1),
                            Math.Abs(y0 - y1));
                    }
```

//finally on mouse move checking the condition

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
                    {
                        foreach (Rectangle rec in listRec)
                        {
                            SelectedRect = MakeRectangle(rec.Left, rec.Top, rec.Right, rec.Bottom);

                            if (
                  (e.X >= SelectedRect.Left) && (e.X <= SelectedRect.Right) &&
                  (e.Y >= SelectedRect.Top) && (e.Y <= SelectedRect.Bottom))
                            {

                                MessageBox.Show("test");
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Also refered this link
        [Drawing Multiple Rectangles c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595585/drawing-multiple-rectangles-c-sharp)

```
I thought this will help some one.

    Thanks
    Dev
```